# Does VPN secure the entire packet only?

Tags: encryption, vpn, ipsec, openvpn

If `VPN` encrypts the entire packet in the established tunnel, what is the difference between `IPSec` and `VPN` in this case? Can be both used in the same time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VPN is a generic term encompassing many approaches and technologies.  IPSec is one approach to encrypting VPN traffic and is used in L2TP and some other VPN protocols.  Cisco OpenConnect VPNs use DTLS instead.   OpenVPN uses SSL/TLS.